# Problema al instalar mysql-server en ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Tengo un problema con las bases de datos MYSQL al intentar instalarla (E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)) (Ubuntu 20.04)

```
root@vmi696975:~# sudo apt install -y mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,548 B of archives.
After this operation, 113 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
(Reading database ... 144839 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Actualiza tu sistema

Antes de instalar cualquier paquete, asegúrate de tener tu sistema actualizado, ya sea por medio del gestor de actualizaciones o por terminal.

Actualizar repositorios:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

En caso de que se encuentren actualizaciones por instalar, vas a recibir un mensaje y debes ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Dependiendo de los paquetes actualizados, es probable que debas reiniciar el equipo.

### Posible solución

Parece haber un problema con el paquete y sus dependencias, puedes tratar de solucionarlo con los siguientes comandos en la terminal:

Resolver dependencias pendientes (opción `-f` o `--fix-broken`):

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Reconfigurar paquetes pendientes (opción `-a`):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Instalar nuevamente MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

En caso de algún error, te recomiendo eliminar MySQL usando el comando `purge` para borrar también archivos de configuración:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
```

Después de esto vuelves a instalar y ya debería funcionar sin problemas.

Referencias:

- [Manual apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/es/man8/apt-get.8.html)
- [Manual dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg.1.html)

Comment: Funciono, pero ahora cuando ejecuto el comando mysql -u root me aparece el siguiente error "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

Comment: Parece que es por los permisos de esa carpeta, revisa [esta respuesta](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/error-2002-hy000-can-t-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-2) (en inglés), ahí están los pasos para solucionarlo.