# Error Otra Vez con MYSQL (Ubuntu 20.04 ) E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, apache2

Tuve unos problemas con la instalación de MYSQL así que decidí desinstalar todo apache (apache2,
y php) e instalarlo nuevamente.

Para esto seguir la guía de [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04-es)

Al ejecutar el código `sudo apt install mysql-server`

(Voy a poner todo el código así pueden ver bien el error y si saben arreglarlo)

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
mysql-server ya está en su versión más reciente (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1).
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  dovecot-core libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data
Utilice «sudo apt autoremove» para eliminarlos.
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
2 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se utilizarán 0 B de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [Y/n] Y
Configurando mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado paquete mysql-server-8.0 script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 127
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de mysql-server:
 mysql-server depende de mysql-server-8.0; sin embargo:
 El paquete `mysql-server-8.0' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete mysql-server (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema al instalar mysql-server en ubuntu 20.04](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/501002/problema-al-instalar-mysql-server-en-ubuntu-20-04)